# Are all standard library header files installed with mingw32-gcc-g++ package?

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, header-files

Are all standard library header files installed with mingw32-gcc-g++ package?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have it *ever* been supported by GCC? It's not a standard header or library, and is rather outdated these days as it's targeted at old DOS applications.

Comment: @SalilGokhale 1) "_Why is this question a duplicate of <...>_" Why, do you think, that it isn't? 2) "_Most of the sample programs on the internet have graphics.h_" I seriously doubt it. "Most example programs from the last millennium" would be closer to the truth.

Comment: @SalilGokhale "_the other one is about how to use graphics.h_" Did you actually read the duplicate? Since.. It isn't about that. It is the broader version of your question: as in, not limited to only one compiler.

Comment: @SalilGokhale "_Are all standard library header files installed with mingw32-gcc-g++ package?_" Yes. Graphics.h isn't a header of a standard library.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Are there any other header files that are essential and I should install? Thanks You

Comment: @SalilGokhale "_Are there any other header files that are essential and I should install?_" Since graphics.h is not in standard library - it isn't essential. What other libraries you deem "essential" is only a matter of preference, and depends solely on your tasks.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks for your help